# How send files in JSON structure from React app to API REST NET Core

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have the following issue.

The project works with a REST API made in NET Core 2.1 and a client that consumes that API created with React 16.
The following structure proposes sending files in forms filled out from the React client in a more or less complex JSON structure. Inside the "Doc" parameter is where the files themselves go, everything else is complementary data to organize them.

```
{
    "Title": "some data",
    "Code": "some data",
    "Files": [
        { 
            "TypeDoc": "some data",
            "IsRequired": true,
            "Doc": "file from form is here!"
        },
        { 
            "TypeDoc": "some data",
            "IsRequired": true,
            "Doc": "file from form is here!"
        },
        .
        .
        .
        
    ]
}
```

My problem is that when sending this structure to the API it is not possible to recognize the files, what's more, the API does not know these files and does not receive it in a normal way since it sends the error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: request
```

if I remove the "Doc" parameter, the shipment works correctly.
At the moment I know that the error is in the way the data is sent from the React app (I'm using Axios as a library to consume the API and I had only sent textual data in JSON before the files) but what I don't know is that if it is possible to send files as in the structure represented above, can the files be sent in a structure JSON to an API or is it necessary to send the files separately?

code to send the JSON structure from the React app using Axios Api consumer:

```
const ClienteHttp = {
    get: (url) => axios.get(url),
    post: (url, body) => axios.post(url, body),
    put: (url, body) => axios.put(url, body),
    delete: (url) => axios.delete(url)
};

const registryDocs = data => {
    return new Promise((resolve, eject) => {
        ClienteHttp.post('/RegisterCompany', data)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                resolve(error.response);
            });
    });
};
```

API endpoint, I know it works because if I change the "Doc" parameter to a normal string, the API works perfect, I just add the code to illustrate the environment better.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PersonalController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IMediator _mediator;
        HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>()
        protected IMediator MediadorHerencia
            => _mediator ?? (_mediator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>());
    }

[AllowAnonymous]
public class PasesController : PersonalController
    {
        [HttpPost("RegisterCompany"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> RegisterCompany(RegisterCompany.Ejecuta parametros)
           => await this.MediadorHerencia.Send(parametros);
    }
```

How should I modify the request to send the JSON structure with the files embedded in it?

Comment: Pls post your code in order we could help you to find a bug.

Comment: code to send the JSON structure is uploaded

Comment: Thanks.  pls post the API too

Comment: Done, although the API works correctly for me if I do not upload documents so it is not the problem.

Comment: Hi @hypercarly, any updates about this case? if the answer can help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that when sending this structure to the API it is not possible to recognize the files, what's more, the API does not know these files and does not receive it

If you'd like to pass both files and other additional data from frontend to your API backend, you can try to use and populate a `FormData` object with your HTTP request, like below.

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("Title", "some data");
data.append("Code", "some data");
data.append("Files[0].TypeDoc", "some data");
data.append("Files[0].IsRequired", true);
data.append("Files[0].Doc", file1_here);
data.append("Files[1].TypeDoc", "some data");
data.append("Files[1].IsRequired", true);
data.append("Files[1].Doc", file2_here);

//...

const registryDocs = data => {
    return new Promise((resolve, eject) => {
        ClienteHttp.post('/RegisterCompany', data)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                resolve(error.response);
            });
    });
};
```

Apply `[FromForm]` attribute to action parameter

```
public IActionResult RegisterCompany([FromForm]MyTestModel parametros)
{
    //...
```

Model classes for testing purpose

```
public class UploadDoc
{
    public string TypeDoc { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Doc { get; set; }
}

public class MyTestModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<UploadDoc> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

*Data sent from frontend*

[image]

*Data received in API action*

[image]